# How can i find the ESR of a capacitor using datasheets?

Tags: capacitor, circuit-design, datasheet

I'm trying to find the ESR of the capacitor C0402C123K4PACTU but due to no avail, i can't find it. I've searched online on how to do so but all of the ones i've searched has a specific part of the datasheet that they can use to calculate the ESR, but this specific capacitor's datasheet doesn't have it (for example the table with tan(δ). Any help will be appreciated. Datasheets are as follows: [data sheet for C0402C123K4PACTU](https://www.mouser.in/datasheet/2/212/KEM_C1006_X5R_SMD-1103249.pdf) and [specification sheet](https://api.kemet.com/component-edge/download/specsheet/C0402C123K4PACTU.pdf)

Comment: You need the datasheet for that specific capacitor, not the series it is part of. If it's not available or the manufacturer didn't bother to put ESR into it, then you are stuck. It's not something you can calculate without having enough information and knowledge to model the capacitor (which even if you had the knowledge you wouldn't have the information because the manufacturer provide it).

Comment: Note well that ESR is a strong function of frequency when it comes to ceramic capacitors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you go to the manufacturers website, Kemet.com, and search for your part, you will get all the information you need.

Including the [specification sheet](https://www.kemet.com/specsheet/C0402C123K4PACTU) with ESR and impedance charts.

I don't know what is up with the specification sheet you linked to yourself, or why that doesn't include the charts.

Answer (score 1):

Plenty of capacitors don't have a specified ESR. If your application is sensitive to ESR, and your capacitor doesn't specify an ESR, you have three options:

- Find a different part that specifies its ESR
- Buy several of the part (from different lots/distributors if you need to) and measure their ESR until you're satisfied with the data
- Just use it and see if it works, ceramic capacitors usually (usually!) have low ESR, so if your only concern is that it may be too high (and not too low) it may well turn out to be fine. But it may not.

Answer (score 1):

Murata’s SimSurfing tool lists ESR and ESL for specific capacitors.

Comment: Also lists change in capacitance with bias voltage, which can be really helpful to know.

Comment: This is not a Murata part.

Comment: Murata surely has a cross for it.

Answer (score 0):

Kemet has K-Sim that gives all sorts of graphical info on their parts.

https://ksim3.kemet.com/capacitor-simulation

I've done comparisons using an impedance analyzer (HP4194A) and found that some of the K-Sim data doesn't match with reality. If you need acurate information on a capacitor, you need to measure it yourself.